# How to multiply a column by array element in linux/awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have an array and want to multiply a column of a file with the array elements. But the multiplication with array element is not working.

Input.file

```
chr1    100    150    3.5
chr1    200    450    10.5
chr1    300    950    9.5
.....
```

Expected output

```
2
21
19
....
```

Code:

```
array=(2 3 4 5)

awk '{print $4*"${array[0]}"}' Input.file
```

My shell

```
echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

This multiplication returns all 0 values. What is the problem with my code?

Comment: Evidently your "array" is not being set in awk but in some shell. Please update the question with a tag for what shell you are using and show the exact code you use to set the "array".

Comment: Thanks @Jeff Y. I have added a tag and shell. Is that what you asked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using only one element of the array, you can pass it as a variable to your awk script

```
 awk -v s="${array[0]}" '{print s*$4}' input.file
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, thanks for the update. You still haven't said which specific shell, but the problem is that everything inside the single quotes is awk-specific, so the `array[0]` in there is an awk variable (associative array), not the shell variable of the same name. Try getting the array reference outside of the single quotes; all you need to do is change those double-quotes to single quotes I think:

```
awk '{print $4*'${array[0]}'}' Input.file
```

To find your shell, you can use the `ps` command and look for processes whose names end in `sh`:

```
$ ps
      PID    PPID    PGID     WINPID   TTY     UID    STIME COMMAND
     2396       1    2396       2396  ?       197612   Oct 16 /usr/bin/mintty
     3480    2396    3480       3424  pty0    197612   Oct 16 /usr/bin/bash
     2500    3480    2500        224  pty0    197612 09:53:03 /usr/bin/ps
```

Common shell names are: `ksh`, `sh`, `csh`, `bash`. Mine is `bash`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jeff Y. It worked perfectly when replaced double quote with single. However, I do not get what you expecting by "You still haven't said which specific shell"? Can you eleborate or specify the command to specify which shell?